# How soon will a person die if they are hung upside down?

Tags: blood-pressure

Sorry if my question is too silly or is in the wrong place.

How soon will a person die if they are hung upside down?

Comment: Probably after a few days without water. Or what do you expect them to die from?

Comment: I don't think this is in scope for healthsciences.  there's plenty of data from crucifixions if you have this morbid interest.

Comment: Assuming adequate food and water were provided, I would expect old age to be the cause of death.

Comment: The range from a few hours to a day,
The mechanism of death is cardiac or pulmonary insufficiency, or a combination of both. How much time it will take depends on the state of health.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting research question from both pathophysiological and historical perspectives:

> **["Upside-down death - the pathophysiology of inversion." Kirsty Andrews. *Pathology.* 2014.](https://www.pathologyjournal.rcpa.edu.au/article/S0031-3025(16)30692-4/fulltext)**
>
> Historically, deaths occurring in a head-down position were generally associated with inverted suspension inflicted upon the victim as a form of torture. In the current day, deaths occurring due to an inverted body position are rare and are usually the result of freak accidents which often attract media attention due to the unusual nature of the death. Occasionally an element of inverted suspension is present in deaths occurring in motor vehicle incidents when the vehicle rolls, coming to rest on its roof with the unconscious victim left suspended upside-down by the seat belt.

---

Early research indicated that inversion-related death would take "some hours" in healthy individuals.

> **["Death in a head-down position." Burkhard Madea. *Forensic Science International.* 1993.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8307521)**
>
> Dying 
>   in 
>   a  head-down 
>   position 
>   is 
>   rare 
>   and 
>   autopsy 
>   may 
>   reveal 
>   no 
>   morphological 
>   findings 
>   which 
>   explain 
>   the 
>   cause 
>   of 
>   death 
>   sufficiently. 
>   Functional 
>   changes, 
>   mainly 
>   postural 
>   changes 
>   of 
>   circulation 
>   must 
>   be 
>   considered 
>   to 
>   explain 
>   the 
>   cause 
>   of 
>   death.
>
> Case 
>   histories 
>   on 
>   deaths 
>   in 
>   a 
>   head-down 
>   position 
>   are 
>   rare, 
>   but 
>   the 
>   problem 
>   may 
>   be 
>   of 
>   increasing 
>   interest 
>   again 
>   in 
>   connection 
>   with 
>   torture 
>   and 
>   the 
>   forensic 
>   pathologist 
>   may 
>   be 
>   asked 
>   how 
>   long 
>   will 
>   it 
>   take 
>   to 
>   die 
>   in 
>   this 
>   position. 
>   From 
>   the 
>   limited 
>   experience 
>   of 
>   some 
>   recent 
>   case 
>   histories 
>   and 
>   the 
>   experimental 
>   investigations 
>   of 
>   Wilkins 
>   et 
>   al., 
>   it  can 
>   only 
>   be 
>   said 
>   that 
>   in 
>   healthy 
>   persons 
>   it 
>   may 
>   take 
>   some 
>   hours.

---

In unhealthy individuals (even adolescents), inversion-related death can be hastened by obesity and cardiovascular or pulmonary disease:

> **["Positional asphyxia in rollover vehicular incidents." Angela Martin *et al.* *Injury Extra.* 2010.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82589868.pdf)**
>
> A 16-year-old driver with a body mass index (BMI) of 60.8 died
>   after a motor vehicle collision when the vehicle went off the road and flipped over... prior to extrication
>   by emergency medicine personnel he became less and less
>   conscious and eventually became unresponsive. He was suspended
>   in an inverted position for approximately 15 min total. He was
>   pronounced dead at the scene.
>
> Examination of the body at autopsy showed that the
>   approximately 400 pound adolescent had rare petechiae of the
>   conjunctivae bilaterally. The ears, nose, and lips were congested
>   with florid facial petechiae. Internally, the lungs were markedly
>   congested and air-filled... The cause of death was deemed to be positional asphyxia due to
>   the prolonged suspension of the decedent in an inverted position,
>   with a contributing factor of morbid obesity. The manner of death
>   was accident.

---

Finally, an entire chapter of *[Forensic Pathology Reviews Volume 3](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-59259-910-3)* is devoted to this topic (**emphasis** mine):

> **["Death in a Head-Down Position." Achim Th. Schäfer. *Forensic Pathology Reviews.* 2005.](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-59259-910-3_3)**
>
> Based on these cases, it is observed that elderly people, and in particular elderly with preexisting cardiovascular diseases, seem to be more prone to death in a head-down position than others. This suggests that **final heart failure is the cause of death rather than cerebral or pulmonary dysfunction**. Results from human and animal experiments and observations under true and simulated microgravitational conditions confirm this assumption, suggesting that a **prolonged, markedly elevated burden of work for the heart because of increased volume load in an inverted body position eventually leads to death by heart failure**. Other mechanisms, such as suffocation (“positional asphyxia”), reduced blood reflux to the heart attributable to vanishing of blood in the venous system, decreased oxygen supply to the brain after reduced arteriovenous pressure difference, and carotid sinus or baroreceptor reflexes, as well as other factors, seem to play only a minor role, if any, in deaths in head-down position.

Comment: I'm skeptical that a healthy individual would die in a matter of hours or even days. The vague nature of the assertion and lack of supporting sources makes it particularly unconvincing.

Comment: As is mentioned in the linked chapter from *Forensic Pathology Reviews*, the conclusion I emphasized was drawn from 10 well-documented case studies (not exactly "vague" or a "lack of supporting sources"). Each case study is itself a publication from a peer-reviewed journal. I'm happy to share the chapter with you if you'd care to read it. Ages of the "head-down deceased" in the case studies range from 11 months to 85 years and confounding health factors aren't present in all of the cases. The chapter also cites numerous animal models and human microgravity models that draw the same conclusion.

Comment: The final paragraph of the chapter's discussion reads: "Thus, it appears that death in a head-down position is a death of gradual (occasionally sudden) heart failure and not a kind of cerebral death or death by suffocation ("asphyxia"). Of course, asphyxia should be discussed as an additional factor influencing lethal outcome in cases where the victim is caught in very tight openings or similar structures that prevent proper breathing by thorax compression. However, asphyxia should not generally be assumed in all cases of head-down deaths."

Comment: I can only see the abstract of that article so the details you describe aren't visible to me.

Comment: @CareyGregory Your unsubstantiated doubt led me to assume that you don’t have institutional access, which is why I offered to share the chapter with you. As with any good abstract, the methods are included in what *is* freely available: “This chapter examines 10 cases in which the deceased was found in a head-down position.” Regardless, specific details aren’t necessary for presenting convincing evidence that being upside down isn’t conducive to staying alive long-term (on the order of ~hours in healthy people).

Comment: How can doubt be unsubstantiated? You wrote a good answer but you failed to convince me. Simple as that. You're correct that I don't have institutional access, and I would imagine that most readers here don't either. Everything that's part of your answer either needs to be included in the answer or freely available. There isn't really a way to provide individuals with additional info. It all needs to be in your answer.

Comment: I disagree with your later points regarding availability – not everything can be open-access, which is why I usually sift through publications and quote relevant sections in my answers. If someone is genuinely interested in one of the articles I link, they have many options for procurement, including simply asking for it. Your doubt is unsubstantiated in the same way that a theory can be unsubstantiated – you didn’t really bother to look at the presented evidence before you dismissed it as “vague” with a “lack of supporting sources” when it is neither, even if you could only view the abstract.

Comment: The source you seem to be relying on most heavily says, `"elderly people, and in particular elderly with preexisting cardiovascular diseases, seem to be more prone to death in a head-down position than others"`. I don't doubt that's true. My doubt is about healthy individuals, which also excludes the morbidly obese teenager. So why would I spend $219 or drive an hour to a college library in order to read your full answer when the quote you provided doesn't seem to address my doubts? See the problem here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83546/discussion-between-bruce-kirkpatrick-and-carey-gregory).